# HTML5 History API actual URL doesn't exist

Tags: html, api, url, resources, html5-history

I am learning HTML5 history API. The following is what I was able to achieve.

I have a page "a.html" that has all the contents and a link to "b.html". When I click the link, almost all my contents remain same except an image changes. So what I do is write a click handler and avoid loading "b.html" [actually b.html doesn't exist in my server]. I make an XMLHTTPRequest and fetch just the contents needed to be replaced (placed in a file call "xmlres.html", contains just a single img tag)and also update url using pushstate().

Everything works fine. But the problem is if user tries to copy current url "appname/b.html" and open in another page, the resource is not found, as I haven't created "b.html". I don't want to create b.html with full contents again, is there any workaround to solve this problem.

Should I write any event listeners for URL or how should I proceed. Any insight on this would be great help.

Comment: Are you planning on using any server-side code? Or just plain old html with javascript? jQuery?

Comment: Yes, I have server side code too. I am using PHP...
To keep the example simple, I haven't mentioned about server side codes...

Answer (score 2):

I think you're talking about single page applications, commonly known as SPA.

Basically what this concept means is you have let's say an `index.html` and inside that you have a section of each page defaulted to be hidden and via javascript and rest oriented services managing and handling the content of each section based on the users interaction.

The single page applications are well known by using hashtag for navigation, in the provided fiddle this is done with the hash symbol.

You can easily access the hash value via this property:

```
console.log(window.location.hash);
```

Here is a [fiddle I made](http://jsbin.com/upinag/1), The page transitions are fully functional, give me a bit to include history api functionality.

Here is what this fiddle does:

- If you access the base url it will display the index section.
- If you access via url to the base url it will display the index section.
- If you access `/1#sectionname` if that section is available it will show it, otherwise it will show you that the section you've tried to reach is not available, so it will show a not found message.
- History api support via jQuery.
- Navigation through the footer links.

Please be patient as I add history functionality and let me know if you need further details.

Here is the [wikipedia page for Single Page Applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) in case you want to read a bit more.

**EDIT:**

- **[Here is the full fiddle](http://jsbin.com/akizej/7).**

I've also made a [blog post about it](http://devisfun.wordpress.com/2013/05/20/demistifying-html5-history-api-hash-push/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have been working with Single Page Architecture extensively. The reason I am looking for HTML History API is, hash bangs, they are bad for search engine optimization. History API provides clean URL that are search engine friendly.
I will wait till you add history api... Thanks a million for your help

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article that describes the phenomenon you're experiencing (at the bottom of the article):
http://www.sitepoint.com/an-overview-and-usage-of-javascript-history-api/

Essentially this boils down to having a special server capability of understanding what to do when a 404 URL is requested directly. The article referenced shows how this is done using PHP. Other application servers such as Node, Vertx, Servlet Spec'd servers all give you special access to the URL handling which lets you determine if a 404 would happen or not, and give you special control when it would be a 404. This is a special case of the history API that is not talked about. There are some additional issues that can come up because of it. For example when using this technique it might still be a good idea to serve up a 404 when the physical resource AND the SPA resource does not exist. The virtual resource being that page that would come up once the history API/URL routing has taken place within the SPA codebase. This would of course assume that the server knows a little about how the routing within the SPA works.